# What does これ以上 (kore ijou) mean?

Tags: translation, meaning, words

The whole sentence reads

> これ以上　シャレてる時間はない

which is from the lyrics of [this](http://lyrics.wikia.com/%E5%92%8C%E7%94%B0%E5%85%89%E5%8F%B8_%28Kouji_Wada%29:Butter-Fly) anime song and, according to [this](http://www.allthelyrics.com/lyrics/digimon/butterflyenglish-lyrics-784495.html) website, means

> There's no more time to be fooling around

I understand the first three lines, and the English translation seems to be literal.

I know that これ means "this". According to JGram, 以上 means "as long as", i.e., as long as you are a student 学生である以上は, etc. However, I'm not sure what これ以上 means and whether the これ is the same one that means "this". I think シャレてる時間はない already means "there's no more time to be fooling around".

Comment: here is over 100 simple examples: ( http://jisho.org/sentences?jap=これ以上&eng= ) copy and paste what is btwn parentheses

Answer (score 15, accepted):

これ by itself means "this" and これ以上, then means "beyond this" or "more than this". これ以上+neg. means, then, "no more than this".

You could expand the above sentence to

> この時間以上(は)シャレてる時間はない。
>   I don't have time (to fool around), beyond the time I have spent already fooling around.

Just to give another example:

> これ以上はできない。
>   I can't do any more. (lit. I can't do more than this.)

Answer (score 4):

So Rikai-chan says that 以上 means: `(n-adv,n-t) not less than; ... and more; ... and upwards; beyond ... (e.g. one's means); further (e.g. nothing further to say); more than ... (e.g. cannot pay more than that); (P)`

So it seems it's emphasizing that: **beyond this point**, there's no more time to fool around.

It seems to be more likely to be in sentence with verbs that are in negative conjugation as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to what has already been said, minna no nihongo, chuukyu 1, chapter 3, translates これ以上 as "any longer".